# How do I center text in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift3, swift-playground

In a Swift playground, how do I center a `UILabel` inside of a `UIViewController`?

When I use `title.center = CGPoint(x: vc.view.frame.width / 2, y: 20)` the text goes off of the screen.

This is the problem

[image: problem]

If it helps, here's my code.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport


// Set up ViewController and other things
var vc = UIViewController()
vc.view.frame.size.height = 75
vc.view.backgroundColor = .white

let title = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 50))
title.textAlignment = .center
title.center = vc.view.center
title.text = "Which code is correct?"
vc.view.addSubview(title)

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = vc
```

Comment: try title.center = self.view.center

Comment: @Harambe Squad http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34645943/how-to-center-uilabel-in-swift

Comment: title.center = GCPoint(x:self. view .bounds.size.width / 2.0, y:self. view .bounds.size.height / 2.0)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to center UILabel in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34645943/how-to-center-uilabel-in-swift)

Comment: Still not working

Comment: @the4kman Nope those solutions don't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The special problem with swift playgrounds is, that the actual frame of the view controller will only be updated correctly, *after the view is loaded / displayed on screen*. That means putting the line for centering the label after the line for setting the live view should help:

```
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = vc
title.center = vc.view.center
vc.view.addSubview(title)
```

Answer (score 0):

If we're talking about top view in hierarchy (i.e. view controller's view), this line should be enough:

```
title.center = vc.view.center
```

Otherwise, if you ever want to center your view/label/button/whatever inside any view controller view's subview — the next solution is universal:

```
title.center = CGPoint(x: parentView.bounds.size.width / 2, y: parentView.bounds.size.height / 2)
```

If you want to center only horizontally or vertically — modify `y` or `x` parameter of `CGPoint(x:y:)` function correspondingly:

```
// Center horizontally but with vertical offset of 20 points
title.center = CGPoint(x: parentView.bounds.size.width / 2, y: 20 - title.bounds.size.height / 2)
```