# Center UILabel created in code using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, center

This may be the simplest thing you can possibly due in Xcode in Swift and for some reason, it is not working properly.

I want to center a label in a view. The only other thing in the view previously was a webView added programatically but for now I have removed that so basically, I have an empty VC in which I'm trying to center a label.

There are [umpteen answers on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34645943/how-to-center-uilabel-in-swift) about this and I've tried every combination but can't get it to to work.

Can anyone suggest a foolproof way to accomplish the simple task of centering a UILabel?

Below is the code I currently have and steps I've taken along with result:

I created an empty view controller in Storyboard and embedded it in a navigation controller.
I set the View Controller in Storyboard to my swift VC class. I also have already cleaned project, closed and re-opened XCode and also deleted storyboard and recreated it in case it was corrupted. Still nothing works.

```
 myVC.swift
 import UIKit

class myVC: UIViewController,WKScriptMessageHandler, WKNavigationDelegate,WKUIDelegate {
    
    var title= "Hello there"     
    var loadingLabel = UILabel()
 
   override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.uiDelegate = self
         loadingLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false  
      // loadingLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
       // loadingLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
       // loadingLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.center.y, width: 290, height: 70))
        loadingLabel.center = self.view.center
        loadingLabel.textAlignment = .center
       loadingLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Halvetica", size: 18.0)
        loadingLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        loadingLabel.text = "TEXT I WANT TO CENTER"
        loadingLabel.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
        loadingLabel.center = self.view.center
        self.view.addSubview(loadingLabel)     
        self.title = title
    }        
    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
     }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `loadingLabel` as subview before adding the constraints.

```
view.addSubview(loadingLabel)
loadingLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false 
loadingLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
loadingLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: Thank you!  Do you know how you would add a multiplier to the vertical constraint of 0.2 so the label is closer to the top?

Comment: Not sure, but will try to figure out. Ask this on another post and post the link below, I'll take a look and try to help out for sure.

Comment: Thx. I asked question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63042552/add-multiplier-to-nslayoutanchor-constraints-in-swift

Comment: That was pretty fast, will take a look.